# Removing a table from a PPT using apache POI Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I can remove table rows from PPT using apache POI Java however my requirement is to remove entire table from PPT. Any thoughts ?

Comment: "Any thoughts?": `XSLFTable` extends `XSLFGraphicFrame`, `XSLFGraphicFrame` extends `XSLFShape`. And there is [XSLFSheet.removeShape](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSheet.html#removeShape-org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFShape-). Any questions?